# Can I add dependencies after using catkin_create_pkg?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used first

```
catkin_init_workspace
```

and thereafter

```
catking_create_pkg example1 roscpp rospy std_msgs
```

and building a simple example file works flawlessly.

Now if I run

```
catkin_create_pkg example2
```

without specifying dependencies, it doesn't work, even though I edited the package.xml and imported exactly the same source code. The reason I want to do this, is I need to move some source code from Fuerte to Hydro, and I'd rather just copy the <build_depend> tags from one xml file to the other. But it doens't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159061/can-i-add-dependencies-after-using-catkin_create_pkg?/) by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2014-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-30**:
What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I need to add dependencies in CMakelist also, and I had not seen the one at the top

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
)

---

Originally posted by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) with karma: 157 on 2014-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-30**:
This looks like CMakeLists.txt, not package.xml.